# How can I test multiple web requests to my web server?

Tags: asp.net, http

I am using asp.net
and I would like to test a few hundreds concurrent requests to the same page, and get a result.

I don't need it via browser.
Just a tool that sends requests and prints the result
Is there such tool?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LoadUI](http://www.loadui.org/) is a good tool.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).